# How to make SO tags autocomplete with Ajax

Tags: asp.net, ajax, autocomplete

Can anybody tell me how can I implement something like the Stack Overflow tags autocomplete textbox, with Ajax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest and simplest way is using the [AutoCompleteExtender](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx) in the [Ajax Controls Toolkit](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/).

This uses a WebService to feed data to the control and can be linked to an existing TextBox. However you can also make use of a PageMethod to feed the extender.

Alternatively you can roll your own using JavaScript and the ScriptManager, however it can be quite tricky. I have recently tried with JQuery and it is definitely simpler.

Comment: Ajax Controls Toolkit is definitely easy to implement, however it generates really huge js files [typically .axd files seen in "view source"] compared to the jquery based ajax

Comment: Agreed. However there is some methods to compress these files. JQuery is a better option but not all environments allow it's use. For example we are only allowed to use Asp.Net Ajax and not JQuery.

Answer (score 2):

I would highly recommend looking at this [jquery autocomplete plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/) which i have used on several of my web projects with fantastic reviews from the customers.

Comment: I believe that SO actually uses that plug-in.  Well they did before they allowed wildcards.  One of the latest posts on the SO blog talks about a new plug-in they are using.

Answer (score 1):

first you will have to create a webservice for retriving words

http://www.csharpcorner.com/UploadFile/raj1979/AutoComplete02142008113654AM/AutoComplete.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest getting a copy of the excellent book ["Pragmatic Ajax"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0976694085) which walks you through just such an example.